# A good approach to implement end-to-end encryption for a groupchat application in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, express, security, encryption, end-to-end

I'm experimenting with a self-made groupchat application, similar to Slack. It currently has the notion of public channels, private channels and one-to-one channels, all using a common datastructure 'room'. To implement this application I'm using node.js, express and socket.io.

My next goal is to implement end-to-end encryption for this application. I think the best approach would be to base this encryption around rooms rather than users. However, I am relativly new to security and node.js. I already did a lot of searching on how other web applications (eg. WhatsApp) do it and what a good approach would be for an application of my kind, but with no great succes.

That's why I came here to ask a rather broad question: what would be a good starting point for me to start of from? Additionally, if someone is rather knowledgable about this topic, I am curious, what are some of the best practises?

Thanks in advance, if you require mort details or information, feel free to ask and I will try to provide them!

Comment: This is a pretty broad question, but I recommend reading up on the topic over at https://security.stackexchange.com/.  Encryption has a lot of "gotchas" around its usage.  Years ago, I found this out the hard way by not understanding the difference between ECB and CBC.  (Check out some examples here:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_(ECB) )  By all means though, experiment and read up on best practices so you can start to learn.  After that, I'm sure you'll have more specific questions you can ask.

Comment: "I think the best approach would be to base this encryption around rooms rather than users." If that's to mean that there's a key per room that's flawed: you cannot get e2e encryption without every user or device (i.e. the ends of the communication) having their own encryption key(s), by definition. WhatsApp uses the Whisper protocol, but that's certainly not a beginner-friendly read. You can perhaps find simplified explanations of how PGP works and start from there. Just don't assume that what you come up with is secure by any professional standard.